# Can I walk through my process' page table in userspace?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

Can anyone suggest some learning materials to accomplish my question?  I'm working with the Linux kernel.

I'm planning on conducting an experiment, but need access to my process' page table, and so far have only found kernel space code to accomplish what I want.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK such interface doesn't exist. What kind of information do you need? Maybe /proc/pagemap will help you (i.e. virtual to physical page mappings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably find the information you want in the proc filesystem, under `/proc/self`. In particular `/proc/self/maps` contains the list of memory mappings in the process, with an indication of their permission and file when applicable. There is a little more information in `/proc/self/smaps`. You'll have to look in the kernel documentation for the format, specifically [`Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Accurate memory metrics can be given by pagemap kernel interface - utilized in libpagemap library https://fedorahosted.org/libpagemap/. Library provides also userspace utils so you can start monitor memory immediately.